How to Comparing Custom Malloc Package (CMU Malloc) with Standard Allocators Using Benchmarks
I am currently working on the CMU Malloc Lab and I have implemented my own malloc package in mm.c. I would like to benchmark my implementation not only with the Malloc Lab grading script but also against other standard allocators using different benchmarking tools.
Is there a way to modify the Malloc Lab code to hook my custom allocator for such comparisons? Alternatively, are there any other benchmarking tools or methods that I can use to evaluate the performance of my allocator against others?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
While examining the Malloc Lab grading script, I discovered that it allocates virtual heap space using malloc() and then measures the performance of the mm_malloc()/mm_free() algorithms implemented in my mm.c within this space.
I am curious if there is a way to modify my code to hook into glibc's malloc instead, allowing my custom allocator to use it. Is this possible, and if so, how can I achieve it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
